# How to constantly read in updated values from Firebase in ios app

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have data that is constantly being updated in firebase and I need my app to pick up on and display the changes in a label.

I have tried using a forever loop, but it only crashes my program.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setuplayer()
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("distance/val").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot.value!)
        self.obstacledistance.text = snapshot.value! as? String
    }
}
```

The expected output is the obstacledistance label to keep updating with the new values read in, but at the moment it is just blank.

Comment: If your app crashes, find the exact error message and stack trace and add them to your question please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using observeSingleEvent use only observe. It will change automatically when values have changed. Code below:

```
   let ref = Database.database().reference()
   ref.child("distance/val").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
       print(snapshot.value!)
       self.obstacledistance.text = snapshot.value! as? String
   }
```